# Failed Raid 10 Disk - Cannot mount raid to recover

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, raid, mdadm

New to Linux and Ubuntu.
I am running Ubuntu version 14 with 4 x 2TB drives in a raid 10 array. 2 of the drives have failed and I cannot get the array to mount in order to fail the drives and add new ones to the array. I have replaced the drives and set up the new ones with partitions exactly the same as the others so they can be added to the array but I cannot get the array to mount so I can add the new drives to the array?
I am using an SSD for the boot drive so the system boots to the OS without any problem. Is there a way to get the array mounted so I can add the new drives in hopes of restoring the array and data?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

A RAID 1,0 array (a.k.a. RAID 10, 1-0, ...) protects against a single drive failure and *if you're **extremely lucky** against a dual drive failure.*

Looks like you *weren't* extremely lucky, so you'll have to fail the entire array and restore your data from a back-up...

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**